# App store still showing beta release of El Capitan months after withdrawal from beta programs?

Tags: macos

Months after withdrawing from the beta program, following the guides for exiting, and then installing the production release of OS X 10.11 and installing 10.11 back when it was new, then restoring from a Time Machine backup prior to installing the beta release, everything was fine except app store still offers me beta releases. How can I stop this? Right now I am on OS X 10.11.2 the app store is offering me 10.11.4 beta though 10.11.3 is the current OS X version.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me! After unchecking the beta software enrollment in the system settings, I ran:

`sudo softwareupdate --clear-catalog`

`man softwareupdate` doesn't document this flag, but it seems to clear pending updates from the App Store, and on the next run of the App Store it will repopulate based on the current configuration of your system, therefore it will not show the beta update, but it will still show other regular updates for your system.

man page: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/softwareupdate.8.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  .  You also don't want to provide link only answer as those links can go stale (and often do on apple.com) resulting in a "broken" answer.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: Still, this answer should be marked correct! After opting out of the beta updates, MacOS Sierra still displayed the next beta of MacOS, but the command in the answer reset the catalog to "production" as the terminal output said.

Answer (score -1):

Try following these steps, and no more beta software should ever show up in the App Store.

1. Open System Preferences and click App Store.
2. Find "Your Computer Is Set to Receive Pre-Release Software Update Seeds"
3. Click "Change"
4. Select "Do Not Show Pre-Release Updates."

*http://www.macworld.com/article/2990027/operating-systems/how-to-leave-the-os-x-beta-program.html*

Comment: I did that, it was part of 'following instructions'. That option has not been available to me for months.

Comment: Against my better judgement I upgraded to the beta version. I'd really like to get the App Store only notifying me of production releases.

Comment: The 'upgrade' said the beta, 10.11.4 in the app store for me but the actual version installed was 10.11.3 , the production  upgrade.